# Pandas groupby date and sum the hours

Tags: python, pandas, csv, aggregate, pandas-groupby

Previously, I have a `attendace.csv`  data to store as `DataFrame` like below snippet, but in this case `Date Received` doesn't used.

```
PIN,Name,Location,Serial Number,Date Time,Type,Status,Date Received
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-24 08:58:14,-,1,2019-10-24 09:05:55
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-24 08:03:53,-,1,2019-10-24 08:11:29
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-24 07:57:04,-,1,2019-10-24 08:05:57
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-24 07:56:46,-,1,2019-10-24 08:05:21
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-24 07:38:37,-,1,2019-10-24 07:46:24
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-23 22:21:50,-,1,2019-10-23 22:29:38
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-23 17:16:19,-,1,2019-10-23 18:52:28
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-23 17:15:18,-,1,2019-10-23 18:51:10
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-23 17:07:36,-,1,2019-10-23 18:36:48
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-23 16:58:45,-,1,2019-10-23 18:07:12
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-23 16:47:27,-,1,2019-10-23 17:30:04
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-23 16:47:22,-,1,2019-10-23 16:55:13
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-23 12:05:04,-,1,2019-10-23 12:13:44
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-23 08:41:38,-,1,2019-10-23 08:55:52
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-23 08:38:39,-,1,2019-10-23 08:46:44
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-23 08:11:14,-,1,2019-10-23 08:26:00
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-23 08:07:07,-,1,2019-10-23 08:14:50
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-23 08:03:17,-,1,2019-10-23 08:10:55
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-22 16:02:37,-,1,2019-10-22 18:56:20
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-22 16:00:07,-,1,2019-10-22 18:28:52
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-22 15:59:52,-,1,2019-10-22 18:18:08
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-22 15:58:56,-,1,2019-10-22 16:10:29
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-22 15:50:55,-,1,2019-10-22 15:58:41
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-22 15:47:54,-,1,2019-10-22 15:55:23
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-22 09:08:36,-,1,2019-10-22 10:55:58
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-22 08:15:08,-,1,2019-10-22 08:45:56
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-22 08:10:19,-,1,2019-10-22 08:35:50
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-22 07:56:50,-,1,2019-10-22 08:30:49
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-22 07:46:25,-,1,2019-10-22 08:16:28
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-22 07:38:46,-,1,2019-10-22 07:46:38
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-21 17:18:12,-,1,2019-10-21 21:15:52
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-21 17:16:03,-,1,2019-10-21 20:16:54
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-21 17:07:18,-,1,2019-10-21 20:15:38
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-21 16:57:53,-,1,2019-10-21 19:30:43
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-21 16:54:14,-,1,2019-10-21 18:00:57
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-21 16:53:58,-,1,2019-10-21 17:01:43
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-21 12:17:06,-,1,2019-10-21 16:15:55
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-21 10:00:36,-,1,2019-10-21 11:36:04
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-21 08:48:34,-,1,2019-10-21 10:50:02
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-21 08:06:25,-,1,2019-10-21 10:49:22
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-21 08:06:20,-,1,2019-10-21 08:37:55
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-21 07:56:15,-,1,2019-10-21 08:04:18
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-18 17:03:27,-,1,2019-10-18 20:35:52
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-18 16:52:19,-,1,2019-10-18 20:20:57
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-18 16:41:01,-,1,2019-10-18 19:21:03
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-18 16:40:46,-,1,2019-10-18 19:05:58
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-18 16:31:30,-,1,2019-10-18 18:22:47
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-18 16:30:12,-,1,2019-10-18 18:05:50
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-18 12:41:13,-,1,2019-10-18 13:27:00
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-18 09:17:12,-,1,2019-10-18 09:25:21
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-18 08:25:55,-,1,2019-10-18 08:43:31
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-18 08:20:18,-,1,2019-10-18 08:28:14
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-18 07:44:38,-,1,2019-10-18 08:11:54
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-18 07:44:34,-,1,2019-10-18 07:52:30
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-17 18:14:34,-,1,2019-10-17 20:40:51
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-17 16:58:25,-,1,2019-10-17 20:25:37
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-17 16:51:01,-,1,2019-10-17 19:25:54
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-17 16:41:10,-,1,2019-10-17 18:26:56
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-17 16:32:20,-,1,2019-10-17 18:26:28
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-17 16:31:05,-,1,2019-10-17 18:25:49
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-17 16:30:22,-,1,2019-10-17 18:10:50
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-17 09:41:27,-,1,2019-10-17 17:41:41
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-17 08:55:40,-,1,2019-10-17 17:11:06
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-17 08:21:08,-,1,2019-10-17 15:11:04
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-17 08:17:35,-,1,2019-10-17 10:15:56
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-17 07:58:43,-,1,2019-10-17 08:20:08
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-17 07:58:32,-,1,2019-10-17 08:06:24
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-16 17:01:24,-,1,2019-10-16 20:16:18
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-16 17:00:48,-,1,2019-10-16 20:15:51
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-16 16:58:37,-,1,2019-10-16 19:00:45
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-16 16:58:30,-,1,2019-10-16 18:47:12
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-16 16:56:04,-,1,2019-10-16 18:45:49
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-16 16:41:20,-,1,2019-10-16 18:31:07
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-16 16:39:42,-,1,2019-10-16 16:47:27
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-16 10:19:20,-,1,2019-10-16 10:26:51
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-16 08:30:16,-,1,2019-10-16 09:13:04
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-16 08:14:00,-,1,2019-10-16 09:10:51
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-16 08:08:07,-,1,2019-10-16 08:43:43
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-16 08:06:24,-,1,2019-10-16 08:14:04
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-16 07:24:06,-,1,2019-10-16 07:31:58
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-15 17:14:36,-,1,2019-10-15 21:55:54
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-15 17:04:43,-,1,2019-10-15 20:56:08
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-15 16:55:05,-,1,2019-10-15 20:11:24
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-15 16:30:40,-,1,2019-10-15 18:11:07
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-15 15:46:47,-,1,2019-10-15 15:54:59
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-15 11:52:38,-,1,2019-10-15 12:00:55
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-15 08:18:21,-,1,2019-10-15 08:27:00
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-15 08:15:47,-,1,2019-10-15 08:26:35
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-15 08:11:19,-,1,2019-10-15 08:25:57
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-15 08:11:14,-,1,2019-10-15 08:25:30
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-15 08:08:37,-,1,2019-10-15 08:16:31
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-14 17:17:06,-,1,2019-10-14 19:55:48
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-14 17:16:56,-,1,2019-10-14 18:40:53
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-14 17:05:49,-,1,2019-10-14 18:25:51
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-14 17:00:37,-,1,2019-10-14 17:08:30
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-14 11:30:30,-,1,2019-10-14 12:11:07
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-14 10:00:16,-,1,2019-10-14 10:09:36
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-14 08:05:44,-,1,2019-10-14 08:25:50
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-14 08:04:31,-,1,2019-10-14 08:12:14
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-11 16:58:24,-,1,2019-10-11 23:36:15
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-11 16:55:31,-,1,2019-10-11 23:24:21
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-11 16:45:29,-,1,2019-10-11 23:20:47
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-11 16:44:31,-,1,2019-10-11 22:51:01
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-11 16:34:45,-,1,2019-10-11 22:20:41
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-11 16:30:42,-,1,2019-10-11 21:50:54
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-11 09:24:32,-,1,2019-10-11 19:20:54
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-11 08:49:10,-,1,2019-10-11 19:06:04
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-11 08:28:39,-,1,2019-10-11 18:20:50
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-11 08:19:15,-,1,2019-10-11 16:36:03
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-11 07:47:31,-,1,2019-10-11 10:05:52
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-11 07:45:51,-,1,2019-10-11 08:05:49
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-11 07:43:19,-,1,2019-10-11 07:50:54
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-10 17:07:36,-,1,2019-10-10 22:51:00
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-10 16:59:58,-,1,2019-10-10 22:21:01
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-10 16:52:35,-,1,2019-10-10 22:06:28
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-10 16:50:59,-,1,2019-10-10 22:05:51
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-10 16:38:24,-,1,2019-10-10 21:51:02
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-10 15:56:40,-,1,2019-10-10 21:36:06
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-10 12:01:10,-,1,2019-10-10 12:08:58
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-10 08:40:33,-,1,2019-10-10 10:36:02
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-10 08:22:54,-,1,2019-10-10 09:50:47
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-10 08:22:50,-,1,2019-10-10 08:30:36
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-10 07:44:35,-,1,2019-10-10 08:06:34
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-10 07:43:19,-,1,2019-10-10 07:50:38
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-09 17:11:48,-,1,2019-10-09 22:50:51
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-09 17:07:26,-,1,2019-10-09 22:35:41
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-09 17:01:42,-,1,2019-10-09 22:20:58
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-09 17:01:32,-,1,2019-10-09 22:05:36
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-09 16:59:02,-,1,2019-10-09 21:35:50
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-09 14:34:39,-,1,2019-10-09 21:20:50
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-09 10:30:39,-,1,2019-10-09 20:23:51
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-09 08:46:15,-,1,2019-10-09 19:50:48
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-09 08:36:15,-,1,2019-10-09 15:35:43
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-09 08:28:46,-,1,2019-10-09 15:20:37
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-09 08:08:32,-,1,2019-10-09 14:50:53
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-09 08:02:22,-,1,2019-10-09 08:09:57
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 16:06:02,-,1,2019-10-08 22:20:30
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 16:04:35,-,1,2019-10-08 21:35:52
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 16:03:08,-,1,2019-10-08 19:36:08
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 16:00:10,-,1,2019-10-08 18:06:03
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 15:57:35,-,1,2019-10-08 16:51:02
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 15:55:29,-,1,2019-10-08 16:03:51
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 14:38:33,-,1,2019-10-08 14:46:26
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 11:54:51,-,1,2019-10-08 12:05:59
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 11:52:08,-,1,2019-10-08 12:02:38
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 08:21:05,-,1,2019-10-08 09:22:01
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 08:14:48,-,1,2019-10-08 09:20:57
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 08:11:25,-,1,2019-10-08 09:05:42
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 07:59:06,-,1,2019-10-08 08:20:44
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 07:42:56,-,1,2019-10-08 08:06:24
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-08 07:37:09,-,1,2019-10-08 07:44:34
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-07 17:16:04,-,1,2019-10-07 18:05:54
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-07 17:04:44,-,1,2019-10-07 17:54:41
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-07 16:57:29,-,1,2019-10-07 17:51:55
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-07 16:47:23,-,1,2019-10-07 17:06:46
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-07 16:46:57,-,1,2019-10-07 16:54:57
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-07 12:17:38,-,1,2019-10-07 12:25:17
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-07 10:06:57,-,1,2019-10-07 10:16:01
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-07 08:29:16,-,1,2019-10-07 08:38:20
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-07 08:24:37,-,1,2019-10-07 08:38:01
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-07 08:21:36,-,1,2019-10-07 08:35:41
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-07 08:08:55,-,1,2019-10-07 08:16:30
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-04 16:59:22,-,1,2019-10-04 19:47:10
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-04 16:55:36,-,1,2019-10-04 19:31:30
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-04 16:44:36,-,1,2019-10-04 19:31:02
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-04 16:30:15,-,1,2019-10-04 19:01:15
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-04 16:30:03,-,1,2019-10-04 17:01:13
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-04 16:28:27,-,1,2019-10-04 16:38:45
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-04 10:25:54,-,1,2019-10-04 13:45:52
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-04 08:26:44,-,1,2019-10-04 12:03:47
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-04 08:13:43,-,1,2019-10-04 09:45:42
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-04 08:09:00,-,1,2019-10-04 08:47:09
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-04 07:40:32,-,1,2019-10-04 08:45:49
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-04 07:28:36,-,1,2019-10-04 07:36:07
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-03 16:54:14,-,1,2019-10-03 21:01:03
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-03 16:53:26,-,1,2019-10-03 20:47:04
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-03 16:49:10,-,1,2019-10-03 18:46:03
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-03 16:43:24,-,1,2019-10-03 18:30:51
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-03 16:37:29,-,1,2019-10-03 17:31:04
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-03 16:37:13,-,1,2019-10-03 17:15:57
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-03 12:09:20,-,1,2019-10-03 15:46:04
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-03 08:47:07,-,1,2019-10-03 12:46:27
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-03 08:21:13,-,1,2019-10-03 09:01:10
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-03 08:20:12,-,1,2019-10-03 08:46:04
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-03 07:48:45,-,1,2019-10-03 08:16:33
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-03 07:37:32,-,1,2019-10-03 07:44:59
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-02 16:58:38,-,1,2019-10-02 18:47:20
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-02 16:57:55,-,1,2019-10-02 18:15:45
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-02 16:56:30,-,1,2019-10-02 17:47:18
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-02 16:54:22,-,1,2019-10-02 17:46:01
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-02 16:53:30,-,1,2019-10-02 17:04:16
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-02 16:51:10,-,1,2019-10-02 16:58:48
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-02 09:25:25,-,1,2019-10-02 10:31:01
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-02 09:13:42,-,1,2019-10-02 10:30:35
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-02 08:18:51,-,1,2019-10-02 10:16:30
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-02 08:13:01,-,1,2019-10-02 08:45:31
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-02 08:10:55,-,1,2019-10-02 08:18:18
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-02 07:45:45,-,1,2019-10-02 07:52:59
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-01 15:53:19,-,1,2019-10-01 22:05:47
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-01 15:50:02,-,1,2019-10-01 21:06:00
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-01 15:49:27,-,1,2019-10-01 20:39:12
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-01 15:45:48,-,1,2019-10-01 20:36:07
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-01 15:45:40,-,1,2019-10-01 20:21:01
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-01 14:20:13,-,1,2019-10-01 14:27:50
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-01 09:22:39,-,1,2019-10-01 09:30:32
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-01 08:24:20,-,1,2019-10-01 08:51:02
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-01 08:22:07,-,1,2019-10-01 08:29:32
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-01 08:05:17,-,1,2019-10-01 08:13:05
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-01 07:27:22,-,1,2019-10-01 07:36:03
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-10-01 07:27:15,-,1,2019-10-01 07:34:52
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-30 20:28:34,-,1,2019-09-30 22:15:59
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-30 17:11:04,-,1,2019-09-30 22:15:11
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-30 17:09:45,-,1,2019-09-30 22:14:53
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-30 17:08:56,-,1,2019-09-30 21:35:50
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-30 17:08:15,-,1,2019-09-30 21:06:04
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-30 16:51:35,-,1,2019-09-30 20:40:46
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-30 12:40:37,-,1,2019-09-30 20:38:39
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-30 09:37:59,-,1,2019-09-30 18:19:23
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-30 09:03:13,-,1,2019-09-30 18:18:51
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-30 08:10:38,-,1,2019-09-30 09:41:02
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-30 07:58:03,-,1,2019-09-30 08:56:04
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-30 07:39:40,-,1,2019-09-30 07:47:05
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-27 16:47:20,-,1,2019-09-27 19:42:18
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-27 16:43:53,-,1,2019-09-27 19:25:58
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-27 16:42:11,-,1,2019-09-27 17:56:44
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-27 16:41:51,-,1,2019-09-27 17:26:14
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-27 16:40:35,-,1,2019-09-27 17:11:29
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-27 16:32:13,-,1,2019-09-27 16:39:48
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-27 08:27:30,-,1,2019-09-27 09:10:47
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-27 08:22:00,-,1,2019-09-27 08:57:12
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-27 08:08:44,-,1,2019-09-27 08:56:17
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-27 08:08:12,-,1,2019-09-27 08:16:10
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-27 07:42:39,-,1,2019-09-27 07:55:38
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-27 07:35:22,-,1,2019-09-27 07:42:35
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-26 17:12:05,-,1,2019-09-26 21:10:53
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-26 16:59:42,-,1,2019-09-26 20:10:50
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-26 16:58:56,-,1,2019-09-26 19:55:57
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-26 16:54:22,-,1,2019-09-26 17:02:10
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-26 16:36:13,-,1,2019-09-26 16:43:58
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-26 08:24:48,-,1,2019-09-26 16:27:06
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-26 08:23:02,-,1,2019-09-26 15:55:27
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-26 08:17:43,-,1,2019-09-26 15:11:00
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-26 08:17:33,-,1,2019-09-26 14:08:46
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-26 08:17:23,-,1,2019-09-26 08:45:50
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-26 07:32:56,-,1,2019-09-26 07:40:26
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-25 17:13:03,-,1,2019-09-26 00:00:55
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-25 17:02:50,-,1,2019-09-25 23:46:18
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-25 17:00:29,-,1,2019-09-25 23:16:47
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-25 16:56:31,-,1,2019-09-25 22:31:09
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-25 16:56:04,-,1,2019-09-25 22:30:43
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-25 16:32:02,-,1,2019-09-25 21:45:46
5,Dedi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-25 08:34:52,-,1,2019-09-25 21:00:49
1,Fendi,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-25 08:33:21,-,1,2019-09-25 20:17:51
6,Muhashil,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-25 08:28:38,-,1,2019-09-25 18:55:53
7,Achmad,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-25 08:28:28,-,1,2019-09-25 16:02:07
9,khirom,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-25 08:26:43,-,1,2019-09-25 10:31:26
4,Agus Makmun,Head Office,D2655C075F3C0924,2019-09-25 08:12:44,-,1,2019-09-25 08:20:29
```

I have a problem to get the pairs **Date Time**, and also sum the total worked hours with following this rules:

1. Sort the **Date Time** by newest.
2. Find how many **Date Time** attendance in 1 day *per-user* *(**Name**)*.
3. If **Date Time** attendance doesn't pairs, the attendance for this day will be ignored.
4. Find how many hours the user *(**Name**)* worked per-days.
5. FInd how many hours the user *(**Name**)* worked for all times.

What I'm doing so far;

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("attendace.csv", sep = ",")
df['absence_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time']).dt.date
```

[image: original data]

```
df.groupby('absence_date')['Name'].value_counts()
```

[image: count per-dates]

How can I get the ***similiar*** data look like this:

```
| absence_date   | Name         | Worked Hours |
|================|==============|==============|
| 2019-10-24     | Achmad       | 0            |
|                | Fendi        | 0            |
|                | Agus Makmun  | 0            |
| ............   | .........    | ....         |
|                |              |              |
| 2019-10-23     | Dedi         | 13.8         |
|                | Muhashil     | 5.1          |
|                | Fendi        | 8.7          |
```

And also worked hours for all days.

```
| Name         | Worked Hours |
|==============|==============|
| Achmad       | 198.7        |
| Fendi        | 206.2        |
| Agus Makmun  | 200.0        |
| Dedi         | 199.3        |
| Muhashil     | 207.8        |
```

Comment: It looks like people are working night-shifts?! So it probably makes it more complicated as we can not sum per days but need to do consecutive days. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @mgruber yes, you are right. for 1 days user can be absence more than 1 session. which is the 1 session have 2 **Date Time** recorded. If the **Date Time** doesn't pairs, the couple **Date Time** doesn't allow to count.

Comment: I don´t really see how to calculate the hours with your sample data. Is it correct that sometimes its only minutes?

Comment: Is possible change data sample for 5 rows with some pairs? Because now there are not pairs, so all data should be ignored...

Comment: Also be free change datetimes to sample - no minutes and seconds for easy verify solution. Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael I was updated the new data.

Comment: @jezrael please checkout again..

Comment: It seems we not understand each other, please check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) - ugly way :(

Answer (score 0):

I did not quiet get all the thing you've written, but as much as I understand, I try to help you finding those. So far, I've written a piece of code below which hopefully what you are looking for.

From what you wrote, the following are what you are asking;

> Sort the Date Time by newest.
>
> Find how many Date Time attendance in 1 day per-user (Name).
>
> If Date Time attendance doesn't pairs, the attendance for this day will be ignored.
>
> Find how many hours the user (Name) worked per-days.
>
> Find how many hours the user (Name) worked for all times.

For example, I did not get the 3rd one because you did not mention what pairs (or doesn't) with what; but so far I got here by some simple assumptions,
I've defined total worked hours as the time passed between "Date Time" and "Date Received"

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('attendace.csv')

df['Date Received'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Received'])
df['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time'])

df.sort_values(by='Date Time', ascending=False, inplace=True)

df['Worked Hours'] = df['Date Received'] - df['Date Time']
df['Worked Hours'] = df['Worked Hours'].dt.total_seconds() / 3600

# Find how many Date Time attendance in 1 day per-user (Name).
# Find how many hours the user (Name) worked per-days.
daily_worked_hours = df.groupby(['Name', pd.Grouper(key='Date Time', freq='1d')])\
                .agg({'Serial Number':'count', 'Worked Hours': 'sum'})
```

**Output**

```
                   Serial Number  Worked Hours
Name   Date Time                              
Achmad 2019-09-25              2     13.832500
       2019-09-26              2     11.223889
       2019-09-27              2      3.048889
       2019-09-30              2      6.035556
       2019-10-01              2      6.331389
...                          ...           ...
khirom 2019-10-18              2      3.609444
       2019-10-21              2      3.665278
       2019-10-22              2      0.642778
       2019-10-23              2      1.386944
       2019-10-24              1      0.148056
```

,and for the last one.

**Code**

```
# Find how many hours the user (Name) worked for all times.
total_hours = df.groupby('Name')['Worked Hours'].sum()
```

**Output**

```
Name
Achmad         122.513611
Agus Makmun     55.842778
Dedi            85.481944
Fendi          118.021389
Muhashil       136.004444
khirom         105.453889
```

Comment: as I said before, in this case `Date Received` doesn't used. you can see this image to easy understand how to get the pairs https://i.imgur.com/hTbG47B.png